# Mips instruction single cycle datapath

Tags: verilog

```
module mult4_to_1_32(out,i0,i1,i2,i3,s0);
output [31:0] out;
input [31:0]i0,i1,i2,i3;
input [1:0]s0;
always @(s0)
begin
  case(s0)
    2'b00: out=i0;      
    2'b01: out=i1;  
    2'b10: out=i2;
    2'b11: out=i3;  
    default: out=i0;    
    endcase
end
endmodule
```

I want to build 4 to 1 multiplexer in modelsim.

Why do I get this error?

> Compile Error:Illegal reference to net "out".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`out` needs to be a `reg` type to be assigned in an always block.

- IEEE Std 1364-1995 and above

  ```
  output [31:0] out;
  reg [31:0] out;
  ```
- IEEE Std 1364-2001 and above (recommenced)

  ```
  output reg [31:0] out;
  ```

Other problem, `i0` through `3` are in in the sensitivity list of your `always` block. This infers complex latching logic.

- IEEE Std 1364-1995 and above

  ```
  always @(s0 or i0 or i1 or i2 or i3)
  ```
- IEEE Std 1364-2001 and above (recommenced)

  ```
  always @* // or @(*)
  ```